# e.changedTouches[0].pageX - uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, touch-event

Well, i need to get the touch position in hand devices. For that i have use below code

```
var touchX = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
```

on tap I'm getting the position of it as expected. But in the console there is a error thrown as below:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
>       at HTMLDocument.mouseover (index1.html:152)

Can someone help me on this.

Comment: Could you post your code.

Comment: found the answer. We need to use device specific conditions for touch events and mouse event.
    
    var docWidth = window.innerWidth;
    if(docWidth <= 1024){
     var touchX = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
     var touchY = e.changedTouches[0].pageY;
     mouseout(e)
    }
    else{
     var mouseX = e.clientX;
     var mouseY = e.clientY;
    }

Answer (score 1):

found the answer. We need to use device specific conditions for touch events and mouse event.

```
var docWidth = window.innerWidth;
if(docWidth <= 1024){
                var touchX = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
                var touchY = e.changedTouches[0].pageY;
                mouseout(e)
            }
            else{
                var mouseX = e.clientX;
                var mouseY = e.clientY;
            }
```